# Deploy with files from bin\Release

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I´m deploying a project in c# windows forms project, that have a file in bin\Release folder that is needed to run correctly the app(it has some configurations to the use of a dll). when i run the app everything is ok. but if I try to deploy using visual studio, and add the file to the Apllication Folder, doens´t work.  (no error messages, it happens exactilly the same if take that file from the bin\Release folder) 
How can I deploy the project correctlly ?

Comment: Is the file included in your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

config files for DLLs are not used in deployed applications. If you need to tweak the configuration of your dll, copy the corresponding sections to the exe config file.

Only the main assembly configuration is taken.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to include the file in your solution.

Then, you need to set the Copy To Output Folder property to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".